# Flutter: How matrix_gesture_detector rotate in Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: flutter, gesture, matrixgesturedetector

I want to make an APP that can zoom in, zoom out and rotate by the gesture.

I found the package: [matrix_gesture_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector) that can work perfectly in Android but I don't know how to make it rotate in the Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) app, I tried to use the mouse and hold "Ctrl", "Shift", and "Alt" but it can't rotate (only zoom in-out). In Android, I can use 2 fingers to zoom and rotate.

I tried this [example](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/transform_demo4.dart)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't know how to make it rotate in the Linux app, I tried to use the mouse and "Ctrl", "Shift",  and "Alt" but it can't rotate (only zoom). In Android, I can use 2 fingers to zoom and rotate